# what is the security/verification system paypal IPN use called?

Tags: paypal, access-token

In the implementation of an IPN listener: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNImplementation/

I understand the IPN listener verifies that the message sent to it comes from paypal by using these steps:

Your listener sends the complete message back to PayPal using HTTPS POST.

Prefix the returned message with the cmd=_notify-validate variable, but do not change the message fields, the order of the fields, or the character encoding from the original message.

Send response messages back to PayPal

PayPal sends one of the following words back to your listener:

VERIFIED (if the message matches the original) INVALID (if the message does not match the original)

I am very interested in implementing this security feature in a webhook I want to develop but I can't find documentation on how this actually work on server side. what is this verification called?

I assume: paypal saves a request's data in a database before posting it to the IPN listener. When the listener post back the data to Paypal, the latter just checks it is in its database. If it exists, return "VERIFIED" and it not return "INVALID"

Is it that simple? Is it robust?

Answer (score 0):

I think you captured the process flow correctly in your question.  I'm not sure if there is a name for this type of verification, but you could simply call it 'notification validation' (this is inspired by the command that the listener script prepends to the post-back to Paypal, `cmd=_notify-validate`.

Yes, this is robust; but to understand why, it's helpful to understand what the attack vector is that this 'notification validation' aims to prevent.  Imagine you own a website that sells widgets.  An attacker finds your site, and sees that you use Paypal to process payments; then after a bit of poking around, the attacker finds the URL of your listener script.  The attacker puts $10,000 USD of widgets in his shopping cart at your site, then proceeds to the checkout page, which redirects him to Paypal to make the payment.  But then, instead of making the payment at Paypal, he simply spoofs an IPN post to your listener script, mimicking the one that Paypal would make if he had actually made the payment.  You ship the widgets, then realize the next day that in fact no payment was made, and you are now out $10,000.

The purpose of this 'notification validation' is to mitigate this type of attack, by validating that posts to your listener script did in fact come from Paypal.